# Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance. in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Hello I am learning relationship many to many I read the official documentation and use the conventions,
but I can't make the relation many to many I get the error that the property does not exist.

how can I solve that?

Migrations

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

User

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Roles

```
 Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Models:

User

```
 public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Role

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user','role_id','user_id');
    }
```

query:

```
$v = User::get();
 dd($v->roles);
```

Comment: Role::class and User::class is sufficient for relationship. don't use extra field and share your dd result

Comment: the dd returns:Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object

Comment: If you want to get one model do `::first()` or `::find(123)` instead of `->get()`, as @HamidShariati stated, `::get()` or `::all()` will return a `collection` so you will have to iterate it to be able to do `$model->roles`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$v = User::get();` returns a **collection** of `users`. If you get one user, for example, `User::find(1)` you will have access to the roles for this specific user.

Another option is

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userRoles = $user->roles;
}
```

Comment: inside foreach, $users should be $user